# Best design to share class instance between many classes

Tags: java, oop

I am going to create a utility Class `APIUtility`, it wraps a unique Object token generated by the server engine, once I used my username and password to get the Object token, I get the door is opening so I can access the engine anytimes if the token is still alive.

I want to use existing 'APIUtility' once I get the access to avoid unnecessary authentication effort. and with this 'APIUtility' I get directly call many functions to server engine. but right now, I have some else classes, they are under different place to take different responsibility: e.g. build data, logic validation, condition elevation, so these classes both need to have a base line use `APIUtility` to access engine data, do anybody have good design for this? because I fell it every class have a variable `APIUtility` we need set it for create a instance of these classes is not a good design.

Comment: Try LightWeight pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track in my opinion; simple is always best.

Just have all the classes that need `APIUtility` take an instance as a dependency in the constructor.

That way, if you need/want to, you can just instantiate `APIUtility` once and have it be shared.

FYI, this is what some people would call "poor man's dependency injection".

Comment: I know I can set APIUtility for every classes, but I fell it's not good.

Comment: @C.c, I also felt the same when I came across such situation in my project. But there no inbuilt support for such thing in java language and it is much better **than** having public static data or singleton pattern here.

Comment: I think Singleton pattern or public static data is a no, because every client call will have new token then start a new APIUtility. the current instance is only around a client call.

Comment: @C.c Why do you feel it's not good? What's the problem? What are you concerned about? There's nothing wrong with multiple instances of a class if that's what you really need.

Comment: @C.c If instantiating the class in code multiple times is your concern, use a DI container, or create a "factory" method. That way construction of APIUtility wont' be duplicated.

Comment: For example: I will have A->B->C,  B->D, A->F->G  so the all A,B,C,D,F,G will have set method for APIUtility. it will be shared in these classes.

Comment: Indeed you could argue that this approach is superior to Dependency Injection on the grounds that you know exactly where the data has come from. Dependency Injection just "makes it happen" but is a little amorphous.

Answer (score 0):

I would use dependency injection, Spring framework. Another option is to use Singleton pattern.

Comment: I think Singleton pattern is a no, because every client call will have new token then a new APIUtility.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a dependency injection\IOC framework like CDI or spring. I personally like CDI more but that is a personal choice.

With Dependency Injection a Container manages the associations between your classes. If you access a class that has elements inside that needs to be injected the compiler sets these through Constructor-Injection(Constructor) or Setter-Injection(Setter-Method).

Answer (score 0):

I would use spring with [dependency injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators) and a appropriate [bean scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes).

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a case for Inversion of Control or Strategy Pattern.

Overall though I would have to say that maybe your responsibilities are a little mixed up. Is there any reason it can't be a static util class (which takes a token as a parameter)? If no, then you might as well do that, if yes, you should probably think of a more useful name for the class.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a variable of type [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

> `ThreadLocal` can be considered as a scope of access, like a *request scope* or *session scope*. It's a thread scope. You can set any object in `ThreadLocal` and this object will be *global* and *local* to the specific thread which is accessing this object. *Global* and *local*? Let me explain:
>
> - Values stored in `ThreadLocal` are *global* to the thread, meaning that they can be accessed from anywhere inside that thread. If a thread calls methods from several classes, then all the methods can see the `ThreadLocal` variable set by other methods (because they are executing in same thread). The value need not be passed explicitly. It's like how you use global variables.
> - Values stored in *ThreadLocal* are local to the thread, meaning that each thread will have it's own `ThreadLocal` variable. One thread can not access/modify other thread's `ThreadLocal` variables.

[*Java Thread Local – How to use and code sample*](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/11/java-thread-local-how-to-use-and-code-sample/)

e.g. You can have something like that:

```
public class APIUtility {

    private static ThreadLocal<Engine> ENGINE_LOCAL = new ThreadLocal<Engine>();
    
    public static void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        ENGINE_LOCAL.set(engine);
    }
    
    public static Engine getEngine() {
        ENGINE_LOCAL.get();
    }
    
}

class NameValidator {
     
    public void foo() {
        Object obj = APIUtility.getEngine().getSomething();
    } 
    
}
```

See also:

- [Thread-local storage - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage)
- [Java Thread Local – How to Use and Code Sample | Javalobby](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-thread-local-%E2%80%93-how-use)